# Flex items won't vertically expand to accommodate contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The sections of my site are stacked vertically, and the content within each section is vertically and horizontally centered with flexbox.

Each section should fill up the entire screen at minimum, but grow vertically if the contents don't fit. The following works in all major browsers except IE11 (a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykx759p6/1/) if you prefer).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* comment the following out to see the desired outcome */
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; */
}

section {
  /* relevant stuff */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  
  /* unimportant aesthetic stuff */
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #442;
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}


/* more unimportant aesthetic stuff */
section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #553;
}
```

```html
<section>
  I'm a section. Scroll down.
</section>
<section>
  I'm another section. Keep scrolling.
</section>
<section>
  The next section will expand to accommodate its contents.
</section>
<section>
  <!-- a bunch of dots -->
 .<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>
</section>
<section>
  If only it was this easy.
</section>
```

Because of IE11's [min-height](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items) bug, I used the well-known workaround of wrapping my flex container in another flex container. But now my sections no longer expand to accommodate their contents (a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p68f8yz/) if you prefer).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* comment the following out to see the desired outcome */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  /* relevant stuff */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  
  /* unimportant aesthetic stuff */
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #442;
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}


/* more unimportant aesthetic stuff */
section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #553;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  I'm a section. Scroll down.
</section>
<section>
  I'm another section. Keep scrolling.
</section>
<section>
  How did these dots get on me?
</section>
<section>
  <!-- a bunch of dots -->
 .<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>
  
</section>
<section>
  The sections aren't expanding!
</section>
```

What's a clean solution that will work in IE11? It should give me the same result as the first code snippet, but in IE11.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/6p68f8yz/1/ and is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You should add a graphic showing the expected (and actual) behaviour. Why the actual? Because what you see might be caused by a bug which will be not reproducable in the future, you question would be useless then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using standard *percentages*, which often rely on the specified height of the parent element, and render differently among browsers, consider using *viewport percentage units*, which rely simply on the viewport dimensions.

This should be all you need. Tested in Chrome, FF and IE11.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;  /* NEW */
  
  /* unimportant aesthetic stuff */
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #442;
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}

/* more unimportant aesthetic stuff */
section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #553;
}
```

```html
<section>
  I'm a section. Scroll down.
</section>
<section>
  I'm another section. Keep scrolling.
</section>
<section>
  The next section will expand<br>to accommodate its contents.
</section>
<section>
  <!-- a bunch of dots -->
 .<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
 <br><br>.<br><br>
</section>
<section>
  If only it was this easy.
</section>
```

### [Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykx759p6/5/)

*From the spec:*

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! Thank you. I had the mistaken idea that viewport units had poor support. Looking at it now, vh/vw are pretty well supported all over.